# HTML Table Extraction - Export to csv, output breaks due to some rows being different format

Tags: perl, bash, sed, awk, grep

This code works great, but some rows are not following the table scheme. Some times there is a row like this

```
<td colspan="7">
<div class="note">lots of notes here</div>
</td>
```

Which causes the CSV to break, is there a way to ignore these type of rows using the code below?

```
my $te = 'HTML::TableExtract'
     ->new(headers => ['Data1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4',
                       'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6']);

my $csv = 'Text::CSV'->new({ binary       => 1,
                         eol          => "\n",
                         always_quote => 1,
                       });

while (@ARGV) {
my $file = shift;
open my $IN, '<', $file or die $!;
my $html = do { local $/; <$IN> };
$te->parse($html);
}
for my $table ($te->tables) {
$csv->print(*STDOUT{IO}, $_) for $table->rows;
}
```

HERE'S A LARGER SAMPLE OF HTML FILE:

```
<table class="datalogs" cellspacing="5px">
<tr><th>Data1</th><th>Data 2</th><th>Data 3</th><th>Data 4</th><th>Data 4< /th>< th>Data 5</th><th>Data 6</th></tr>
<tr class="odd"><td valign="top"><h4>123<br/></h4></td><td valign="top">AAA</td><td valign="top"><b>url here</b></td><td valign="top">Yes</td><td valign="top">None</td><td valign="top"></td><td valign="top"></td></tr><tr class="even">...</td></tr>
<td colspan="7">
<div class="note">lots of notes here</div>
</td>
</table>
```

HERE'S A SAMPLE OUTPUT CURRENTLY:

```
"Other","JPEG","http://URL/jpg/image.jpg","No","None",,
"Other","JPEG","http://URL/","Yes","None",,
"Other","PNG","http://URL:80/","Yes","None",,
"Othe","GIF","http://URL/GetData?y=1","No","None",,
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why the non-[tag:perl] tags?

Comment: might be another way to do it?

Comment: For a way to generate a CSV file from a table on the browser side, take a look at my [html5csv.js library](http://github.com/DrPaulBrewer/html5csv).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I documentation:

> Tables with rowspan or colspan attributes will have some cells
>   containing undef.

You need to check if all 7 cells having undef value, than ignore row.

```
my $te = 'HTML::TableExtract'
     ->new(headers => ['Data1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4',
                       'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6']);

my $csv = 'Text::CSV'->new({ binary       => 1,
                         eol          => "\n",
                         always_quote => 1,
                       });

while (@ARGV) {
  my $file = shift;
  open my $IN, '<', $file or die $!;
  my $html = do { local $/; <$IN> };
  $te->parse($html);
}

for my $table ($te->tables) {
  for my $row ($table->rows){
    my @val = grep { defined $_ } @{$row} ;
    next if scalar( @val) == 1;
    $csv->print(*STDOUT{IO}, $row);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I just get a blank out put when adding this. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I just added more detailed input/ouput. Thanks